# Cannot open 2 USB cameras simultaneously on VLC player Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: video, webcam, vlc, camera, opencv

Cannot open 2 USB cameras simultaneously on VLC player Ubuntu 12.04

How I open a Camera:
In terminal (text after the $ prompt = commands that I type):

```
$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1
$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x9f2d908] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
```

Now, VLC starts playing camera output.

In another new terminal (text after the $ prompt = commands that I type):

```
$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video1
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x9b24908] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0xb0500960] v4l2 demux error: VIDIOC_STREAMON failed
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
[0xb0501188] v4l2 access error: cannot set input 0: Device or resource busy
[0xb0501188] v4l2 access error: cannot set input 0: Device or resource busy
[0xb5300618] main input error: open of `v4l2:///dev/video1' failed
```

---

No video is played in this terminal's VLC window.

**Primary Objective**: I want to open two cameras simultaneously in opencv (c++) ... got similar errors with opencv .. so I'm using VLC Player to debug the issue.
The errors when opening two cameras simultaneously using c++ opencv ( the code is similar to https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/starter_video.cpp?rev=4705 )

```
e557822@e557822-T740:~/Desktop/Camera/starter_video2$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2
e557822@e557822-T740:~/Desktop/Camera/starter_video2$ ./starter_video2 0 1
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
press space to save a picture. q or esc to quit
init done 
opengl support available 
libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
VIDIOC_STREAMON: No space left on device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just that the bandwidth of the USB ports is not enough to stream the data from the cameras. Try enabling them at a low resolution, or connect them in different ports.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, it may solve your issue. It appears to be an identical situation.

[VLC Forum post](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=74077)